# problem with callback function in javascript

Tags: html, callback, javascript

I am trying to understand callback functions in javascript.

There is a function something like

```
function load() {

 var func = function(data){
  ///

 };
}
```

Can anyone explain me from where the parameter "data" will be returned, as I dont see any variable declared in the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript, functions are [first class objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_object). You could store them in objects (variables) and pass them around as arguments to functions. Every function is actually a `Function` object.

You don't have a callback function in that example. You'd have one when you pass a function as an argument to another function.

This is a function that invokes a callback function when it is ready:

```
function load (ready_callback) {
   // do some stuff

   ready_callback();
}
```

Which can be invoked as follows:

```
function callback () {
   alert('Ready');
}

load(callback);
```

Or:

```
var callback = function () {
   alert('Ready');
}

load(callback);
```

Or:

```
load(function () {
   alert('Ready');
});
```

The above three example are pretty much equivalent.

Callback functions are typically used for event handling and asynchronous methods. One example is the [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) method, which invokes a callback function when a timeout expires:

```
var timerCallback = function () {
   alert('Timeout Expired!');
}

setTimeout(timerCallback, 5000);  // Set the timeout to 5 seconds
```